# Enable, Disable Timer in Python GUI

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I created a Python GUI using QT Creator and PyQt5. I can initiate timers to do functions but these timers once cancelled it can't be enabled again ... I found WXPython has these timers working good but I wort it in QT ... Do you have a solution, for example, a function in a timer, enabled and disabled using two buttons

Comment: Hi, please take a moment to go on the 'tour' page: https://stackoverflow.com/tour
Can you provide what you have tried, what is your error, a minimum reproductible example, etc ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please provide a [mre], read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: @DorianTurba Instead of copying the link you could use `[tour]` that generates [tour], the same for `[ask]` that generates [ask]

Comment: @eyllanesc Haha, thank you I didn't know that !

Comment: @DorianTurba See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments